# Enhancing laravel-echo-server with connect reply

Tags: websocket, socket.io

I use laravel-echo-server for broadcasting messages from my app to my browser.

**My question is**: how can I configure my `laravel-echo-server` to be able to send some messagess to user when they connect to a channel.

I see I could run laravel-echo-server in my code, but is there a way I can "catch" subscribe events?

Answer (score 0):

In your bootstrap:

```
require('./echo-channels');
```

then in your `echo-channels.js` of the same directory:

```
window.Echo.private('Notify.Others')
    .listen('event-name', function (e) {
        console.log(e.method);
    });
```

Not to miss to mention:
RTFM: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting#installing-laravel-echo